# Convert all characters except [0-9] [a-z] [A-Z] to "-" how in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i need a way to convert all characters except [0-9] [a-z] [A-Z] to a "-" how do i do it in php thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$yourString = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/", "-", $yourString);
```

I think that should do it.